# Display leaflet layerswitcher on click event

Tags: leaflet, layer-switcher

I would like to click on a sidebar/menu icon, and when I do the layerswitcher Icon should appear.

[image]

Right now the layerswitcher is always displayed. 
I know how to make it disappear with the command

```
display: none !important;
```

I should establish a connection between the layerswitcher and the menu icon.

The menu works, so when I click their pops out a menu. The code of the sidebar menu in html is:

```
    <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
  <a href="#" class="btn-close"
  onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times; </a>
  <a href="#">Building</a>
  <a href="#">about</a>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">
    bygning
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

It is connected to a click event in js, where the code is:
`function openSlideMenu(){
      document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width
      = '150px';
    }
    function closeSlideMenu(){
      document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width
      = '0';
    }`

The js code of the layerswitcher is:

```
 var overlayMaps= "building": riskByg};
 var byg=L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

I assume it has something to do with the connection of my sidemenu in html. But right now I can only connect to a link, and I want to connect it to an icon.

Answer (score 1):

Initially just define layer control, do not add it to the map:

```
var byg = L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps);
```

When you want to to show it, add it to the map

```
byg.addTo(map);
```

and when you want to hide it, remove it from the map:

```
byg.remove();
```

Comment: I have removed the layerswitcher function from the map. 

When I click the menu icon, i have made it possible to make the icon appear on the map. But I don't know how to remove it. 

my code is as follow:
/* Open and close side bar */
    function openSlideMenu(){
      document.getElementById('side-menu',byg.addTo(map)).style.width
      = '150px';
    }
    function closeSlideMenu(){
      document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width
      = '0';
    }

Comment: Just add byg.remove() call to your closeSlideMenu() function: `closeSlideMenu(){document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';byg.remove();}`.